# I can't to write in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using file cpp and extension C/C++ of IntelliSense and Code Runner.
But when there is a some line like:

```
cin >> number;
```

I can't to write in the terminal some number, but I can´t. I do to click over console (SALIDA) but when I press a number, number isn't written to console (SALIDA).

If I use console, then, I can compile y run good code.

What can I do?

Thanks!

[image: Image here]

Answer (score 0):

The *OUTPUT* tab (*SALIDA* in Spanish) is strictly for, well, output only.

To input, you must edit the Launch Configuration (project_root>/.vscode/launch.json) and set the `externalConsole` flag to `true` ([reference](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/blob/master/launch.md)), and the program should launch in a new console instead of the VSCode's OUTPUT one.